# How do I change the _ga google tag manager query param for cross domain tracking to a different value?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to use Google's UA and GTM and include cross-domain tracking.  The setup is easy enough, but the param it passes by default is _ga to track clients/sessions from one domain to another.

I want to have it track using a different query param due to limitations on one of the domains(the url is cleansed of anything that is NOT t_ params).

If I could use the basic cross-domain link tracking functionality except change the param to t_ga or something, it would work beautifully.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics has (to the best of my knowledge and according to the documentation) no built-in way to change the parameter name for the linker parameter, so you would have to do a workaround.

One way would not to use the autolinker provided by GTM ("linking" here means the process of adding the _ga parameter to outgoing urls), but to create a custom linker.

First you would need a custom javascript variable - let's call it "linker" - to retrieve the linker parameter. The linker parameter already includes the "_ga" parameter name, so you'd need to replace it:

```
function() {
  var trackers = ga.getAll();
  param = trackers[0].get('linkerParam');
  return param.replace("_ga","t_ga");
}
```

Then you need a custom HTML tag for your custom decorator function:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
 link.onclick=function() {
   link.href = link.href + "?" + {{linker}};
 };
})
```

(obviously this need to be rather more elaborate - you need to check if the href points to a linked domain, and if it already includes query parameters. Code is untested and for demonstration only).

On the receiving side you would need to replace "t_ga" with plain "_ga" in your Url, and pass the modified {{Page Url}} to the location field in your Google Analytics tag. Since Google checks the passed in value rather than the original Url it would see the _ga parameter and apply it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just set one of the field names when creating the tag to `t_ga` and then the value to {{your_custom_variable}} where that custom dataLayer variable name is `_ga` :)